# Why String#hashCode uses local intermediate variable for storing hashCode result?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, concurrency, primitive

String hashCode implementation in java 11 looks like this:

```
 public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
            hash = h = isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.hashCode(value)
                                  : StringUTF16.hashCode(value);
        }
        return h;
    }
```

Why do we need `int h` here ? Is it somehow related to thread synchronization ?

Comment: My question is a duplicate of other 2 topics but that topics are not duplicates of each other - interesting

Comment: @gstackoverflow I think they should be (and you can help that by voting on a close reason of the first one).